# Reformat the String after removing a word from it

Tags: java

I have a String as "AASS MON 01 2013 365.00 HJJ Call"

I need to remove the String HJJ from the above String and need the output as

AASS MON 01 2013 365.00 HJJ Call

I tried the following thing

```
if(symbol.contains("HJJ"))
{
symbol = symbol.replace("HJJ","");
}
```

But with this i am getting output as

```
AASS MON 01 2013 365.00  Call  ( One extra space before call )
```

Where i want it to be

```
AASS MON 01 2013 365.00 Call
```

Comment: There are many ways to do this with regex, e.g., `symbol = symbol.replaceAll("\\s+HJJ\\s+", " ");`

Comment: What about `symbol.replace(" HJJ","")` ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure your first wanted output is a typo... you want to remove HJJ and want the output exactly as the input ? :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Trimimg
{
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        String str = "AASS MON 01 2013 365.00 HJJ Call";

        String newStr = str.replace(" HJJ", "");

        System.out.println(newStr);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I usually use:

```
public static String removeExtraSpaces(String input) {
    return input.trim().replaceAll("  +", " ");
}
```

`trim` removes beginning and ending spaces while `replaceAll` replaces any line of spaces by one single space.